# Every menu option rendered as selected. Strange workaround

Tags: react-select

I just upgraded two projects from using react-select 1.2.1 to 2.0.0. The first project is a "demo" for trying out react-select, a simple one based on Create React App. The other project is the serious stuff, including old and new technologies (Java, Maven). In the simple project the new react-select worked as predicted, but in the serious project I found that when I had made a selection and opened the menu again, all the options were rendered as selected!

I then found out about the isOptionSelected property and I tried this in my simple project first:

```
isOptionSelected={(selOpt, selOptArr) => false}
```

As expected, this caused no option to be rendered as selected. However, when I put the same line into the serious project, it cured the problem there; now only the correct option was rendered as selected!

This is the complete Select definition:

```
<Select
  components={{ DropdownIndicator }}
  styles={mySelectStyles}
  placeholder={someText}
  isClearable={true}
  isDisabled={readOnly}
  isOptionSelected={(selOpt, selOptArr) => false}
  noOptionsMessage={() => "No match"}
  value={value}
  onChange={(selectedItem) => {
    if (selectedItem !== null) console.log(...);
  }}
  options={myOptions}
/>
```

I have not been able to find out why the line with isOptionSelected causes different rendering in my two projects. To me it seems like a bug in react-select 2.0.0.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your `value` and `myOptions` props please ?

Comment: Right now, my "serious project" is in a state that prevents me from recreating this problem. I will come back with some details as soon as I can. Thanks.